# slope of lsline changes according to xaxis

Tags: matlab, scatter

I want to fit a lsline (`h=lsline`) to a scatterplot in MATLAB. The data is in the xrange between [-2.5 2.5] and I display them with and xlim of [-3 3]. I want to show the lsline only in the range between [-2.9 2.9].

However, when I add `h.XData=[-2.9 2.9]` the slope of the line changes. Does that make sense to anyone? There is no datapoint between 2.5 and 3 and I expected to only see differences in the length of the line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply change the axis limits after plotting the line:

```
x = -2.5:.125:2.5;

y = .5 .* x + randn(1,numel(x))*.2;

scatter(x,y);

xlim([-2.9 2.9])
lsline;
xlim([-3 3])
ylim([-1.6 2])
```

[image]

Comment: thank you so much! Thats what I did now. However, it still does not make sense to me why that line would change. Shouldn't the best fitting line still be the same if I restrict to a range of X where there are no values of interest anyhow?

Comment: If you change the `XData` property, you chnage the slope. Assume the line goes from `[0 1]` in `x` and from `[0 1]` in `y`. The slope is `1`. If you change the `XData` to be `[.5 1]`, the slope is `2`. Every component in `YData` is related to the respective component in `XData`.